# What's the meaning of "It would have been a beautiful life."

Tags: subjunctives

[image]

This is an image from Yu Yu Hakusho.

He says "it would have been a beautiful life."  Does that mean his life was actually bad and that he is regretting his past?

Comment: What part of the sentence are you unsure about? Do you understand "would have been"?

Comment: This needs more context.

Comment: Generally "It would have been a beautiful life" talks about a hypothetical life, not necessarily that his current life is bad.  Without more context it's really not possible to say if the speaker is expressing any regrets.  Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

This does not necessarily mean that he regrets his life, though it does not preclude it.  I would guess, without any context, that it's more likely that the person he's speaking to regrets *his* life, and it's almost certain that the other character is wistfully wishing that it were different.  This hypothetical life would have involved the speaker in some way and so the speaker can agree that it would have been beautiful.

For instance, Terry Pratchett once had an elderly couple meet, decades after she had refused his proposal, and he wistfully asks her if their marrying would have been a good life.  She snaps that she had a good life, and then, relents to admit that it would have been a good life to marry him, too.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your answer! Is English your mother language?

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou  Yes, it is

Comment: I'm very impressed with your answer! Well done!